# Input textarea on focus remove orange border?

Tags: html, css, input

I've tried everything I can think of to remove this. How can I remove this crazy firefox on focus border? It will highlight with an orange border when I click on the input area.

Here is my CSS

```
.noFocus:focus {
outline: none !important;
border: none !important;
-moz-appearance:none;
}
```

and

```
textarea:focus, input:focus{
    outline: none;
    border: none !important;
-moz-appearance:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for the issue you have-

```
input, select, textarea, button {
    -moz-box-shadow:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Leave a whitespace between `!important` and the `;` , like this:

```
outline: none !important ;
```

That could be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope this works:

```
input:invalid {outline: none;
    border: none !important;
-moz-appearance:none;}
```